# What is the difference between "pace" and "speed" in this context?

Tags: meaning, differences

I understand that **pace** and **speed** are often interchangeable, however, why are they not in this case? Only the latter is correct according to the answer key.

> The lifeguards were on a training exercise in the sea when the
>   dolphins swam towards them at considerable **speed**, then circled them
>   repeatedly, hitting the surface of the water with their fins.

Here are the Cambridge definitions:
[pace](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pace) [speed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speed)

Comment: All I can say is "the answer key" is just someone's *opinion* - with which I disagree. Perhaps the test setter is a bit literal-minded, and thinks that since dolphins don't have ***legs***, they can't move at a ***pace***. In which case I'd just offer [*The kid got into his ambulance and **drove away at a fair pace**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22drove+away+at+a+fair+pace%22)

Comment: "**a** considerable pace" would seem more natural to me (BrE).  That might be the deciding factor?